# Filter DataFrame in Pandas on sum of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
[1] df
ProductIds  A   B   C   D
11210000018 0   0   0   0
11210000155 1   0   0   0
11210006508 0   0   0   0
11210007253 0   0   0   0
11210009431 0   0   0   0
11210135871 1   0   0   0
```

I want to filter the frame by adding each row and if sum is greater than zero then filter that row. For the given condition the result would be like

```
ProductIds  A   B   C   D
11210000155 1   0   0   0
11210135871 1   0   0   0
```

One way of doing that is to add another column with sum and then filter like the following:

```
df['Sum'] = df.sum(axis = 1)
df = df[df.Sum > 0]
df.drop(['Sum']
```

But is there any one liner builtin method to do this ? I cannot add the columns manually because there are thousands of columns. Thanks.

Comment: you could've just done `df = df[df.sum(axis=1) > 0]`

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) if in `DataFrame` are only `0` and numbers higher as `0` - test if in row are all values `0` and then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df == 0).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
ProductIds
11210000018     True
11210000155    False
11210006508     True
11210007253     True
11210009431     True
11210135871    False
dtype: bool

print (df[~mask])
             A  B  C  D
ProductIds             
11210000155  1  0  0  0
11210135871  1  0  0  0
```

More general solution is use `boolean mask` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - is not neccessary create new column:

```
df = df[df.sum(axis = 1) > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

another solutions:

```
In [194]: df.query('A + B + C + D > 0')
Out[194]:
             A  B  C  D
ProductIds
11210000155  1  0  0  0
11210135871  1  0  0  0
```